# How to insert multiple records with the same ID into a table using DAO in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

(1) I have 3 tables (A-Sched,B-Trans and C-ItemRecep) with one Lookup table called D-TransDetailRecep. Below is the relationship diagram.
[image: relationship diagram]

(2) I am inserting values into the table fields from a form through a click button that implements the DAO below:

Public Sub RecpSchedule1()
    'Consultation ONLY
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, rt As DAO.Recordset, rd As DAO.Recordset, ri As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lngTransId As Long
    Dim lngItemRecepId As Long

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Sched")
Set rt = db.OpenRecordset("Trans")
Set ri = db.OpenRecordset("ItemRecep")
Set rd = db.OpenRecordset("TransDetailRecep")
```

lngItemRecepId = Nz(DMax("ID", "ItemRecep"), 0) + 1 'Next ItemRecep ID
   lngTransId = Nz(DMax("ID", "Trans"), 0) + 1 'Next Trans ID

```
    With rs
        .AddNew
        !SDate = Me.txtSchedDate
        !PatientName = Me.cmbPatientName
        !RegNo = Me.txtRegNo
        !DateOfBirth = Me.txtAge
        !Gender = Me.txtGender
        !PatientClass = Me.PatientClass
        !RecepSchedule = True
        .Update
    End With


    With rt
        .AddNew
        !ID = lngTransId
        !SchedRegNo = Me.txtRegNo
        ![Total_RecepFee] = Nz((Me.txtConsFee + Me.txtIOPFee + ![Total_RecepFee]), 0)

       .Update
    End With

    With ri
        .AddNew
        !ID = lngItemRecepId
        !ItemName = "ConsFee"
        !Price = Me.txtConsFee.Value
        !Dept = "Reception"
        .Update
    End With

    With rd
        .AddNew
        !TransID = lngTransId
        !TransID = DMax("ID", "Trans")
        !ItemRecepID = DMax("ID", "ItemRecep")
        .Update
    End With



    rs.Close
    rt.Close
    ri.Close
    rd.Close

 Set rs = Nothing
 Set rt = Nothing
 Set rd = Nothing
 Set ri = Nothing
 Set db = Nothing
```

End Sub

Public Sub RecpSchedule2()

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, rt As DAO.Recordset, rd As DAO.Recordset, ri As DAO.Recordset
Dim lngTransId As Long
Dim lngItemRecepId As Long


Set db = CurrentDb
Set rt = db.OpenRecordset("Trans")
Set ri = db.OpenRecordset("ItemRecep")
Set rd = db.OpenRecordset("TransDetailRecep")
```

lngItemRecepId = Nz(DMax("ID", "ItemRecep"), 0) + 1 'Next ItemRecep ID
   lngTransId = Nz(DMax("ID", "Trans"), 0) + 1 'Next Trans ID

```
    'With rt
       ' .AddNew
       ' !ID = lngTransId
        '!SchedRegNo = Me.txtRegNo
        '![Total_RecepFee] = Nz((Me.txtIOPFee + ![Total_RecepFee]), 0)
       '.Update
   ' End With

    With ri
        .AddNew
        !ID = lngItemRecepId
        !ItemName = "IOPFee"
        !Price = Me.txtIOPFee.Value
        !Dept = "Reception"
        .Update
    End With

    With rd
        .AddNew
        !TransID = lngTransId
        !TransID = DMax("ID", "Trans")
        !ItemRecepID = DMax("ID", "ItemRecep")
        .Update
    End With



    rt.Close
    ri.Close
    rd.Close

 Set rt = Nothing
 Set rd = Nothing
 Set ri = Nothing
 Set db = Nothing
```

End Sub

[image]
(3) My challenge: The field for the Total_RecepFee should show 500 where the Price is 500 and show 1200 where the Price is 1200. (What I have now is that both is showing the sum of the values)

Comment: Thats is not Vb.NET code.  It is VB6 or some legacy/vba variant

Comment: I think VB.NET will tolerate the bang! notation, but the IDE eats the old `Set` keyword @YowE3K

Comment: @Plutonix DOH!!  Of course.  (You can tell it's been a while since I used .Net!)

Comment: Kostas K, could you please help me to look at the code above? It is based on your modification. I am still grateful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
rd!TransID = rt!ID
rd!ItemRecepID = ri!ID
```

The `rt.Update` and `ri.Update` methods have not been run to save the recordset. But even so, `.AddNew` creates a new record therefore `rt!ID` and `ri!ID` are both Null.

You could try to save both `rt` and `ri` recordsets first and then retrieve the Max(ID) (since this will be the last added ID) through the `DMax` function. However, if multiple users have access to add data simultaneously, this could be risky (actually it would be very risky).

I would suggest why not scrapping the autonumber ID and handle it manually?

```
Dim lngId as Long
    lngId = DMax("ID", "Trans") + 1
    'You can now feed it to both tables
```

---

Try the updated code below. I haven't been able to test it myself.

```
Public Sub RecpSchedule1()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, rt As DAO.Recordset, rd As DAO.Recordset, ri As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Sched")
    Set rt = db.OpenRecordset("Trans")
    Set ri = db.OpenRecordset("ItemRecep")
    Set rd = db.OpenRecordset("TransDetailRecep")

        With rs
            .AddNew
            !SDate = Me.txtSchedDate
            !PatientName = Me.cmbPatientName
            !RegNo = Me.txtRegNo
            .Update
        End With

        With rt
            .AddNew
            !SchedRegNo = Me.txtRegNo
            !TDate = Me.txtSchedDate
            .Update
        End With

        With ri
            .AddNew
            !ItemName = "ConsFee"
            !Price = Me.txtConsFee.Value
            !Dept = "Reception"
            .Update
        End With

        With rd
            .AddNew
            !TransID = DMax("ID", "Trans")
            !ItemRecepID = DMax("ID", "ItemRecep")
            .Update
        End With

        rs.Close
        rt.Close
        ri.Close
        rd.Close

     Set rs = Nothing
     Set rt = Nothing
     Set rd = Nothing
     Set ri = Nothing
     Set db = Nothing
End Sub



Public Sub RecpSchedule2()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, rt As DAO.Recordset, rd As DAO.Recordset, ri As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rt = db.OpenRecordset("Trans")
    Set ri = db.OpenRecordset("ItemRecep")
    Set rd = db.OpenRecordset("TransDetailRecep")

        With ri
            .AddNew
            !ItemName = "IOP"
            !Price = Me.txtIOPFee.Value
            !Dept = "Reception"
            .Update
        End With

        With rd
            .AddNew
            !TransID = DMax("ID", "Trans")
            !ItemRecepID = DMax("ID", "ItemRecep")
            .Update
        End With

        rt.Close
        ri.Close
        rd.Close

     Set rt = Nothing
     Set rd = Nothing
     Set ri = Nothing
     Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Update:**

---

In order to handle the IDs manually, you need to determine the next IDs for tables *Trans* and *ItemRecep* upon entering data.

```
Dim lngTransId as Long
    lngTransId = Nz(DMax("ID", "Trans"),0) + 1 'Next Trans ID

Dim lngItemRecepId as Long
    lngItemRecepId = Nz(DMax("ID", "ItemRecep"),0) + 1 'Next ItemRecep ID

With rt
    .AddNew
    !ID = lngTransId 
    !SchedRegNo = Me.txtRegNo
    !TDate = Me.txtSchedDate
    .Update
End With

With ri
    .AddNew
    !ID = lngItemRecepId 
    !ItemName = "ConsFee"
    !Price = Me.txtConsFee.Value
    !Dept = "Reception"
    .Update
End With

With rd
    .AddNew
    !TransID = lngTransId 
    !ItemRecepID = lngItemRecepId 
    .Update
End With
```

Comment: Kostas K. you are awesome! Sorry for the delay. I have tried your modification. I got the the .rs update highlighted and also got the following error message. "Run-time error '3022'
The changes you requested to the table were not successful becasuse they would create duplicate value in the index, primary key or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove teh index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again."

Comment: I changed the index status of table sched to "No" and this makes your code worked. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this application will be multiuser based, how do I implement your code above "lngId = DMax("ID", "Trans") + 1 "above in the code?

Comment: I implemented your update Kostas, But I got this error message: "Run-time error '94'
Invalid use of Null"  Also "lngTransId = DMax("ID", "Trans") + 1 'Next Trans ID" is highlighted when I try to debug.

Comment: @Liberty Crown Infotech Try now, I wrapped the `DMax` with `Nz` for Null values.

Comment: Run-time error '3201'
You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table "Trans". When debug the ".Update " for rd is highlighted on Schedule2()!

Comment: Have you changed the autonumber ID field to Number?

Comment: The Only table I have autoID now is the Sched. Should I change that also to Number?

Comment: Even after changing the Sched ID to Number, The error persists.

Comment: I presume you have updated Schedule2() to incorporate the manual ID solution, yes? The updated answer below is just a sample which needs to be incorporated in both Subs.

Comment: No. I incorporated it on both subs.

Comment: Is the form bound to the table? If yes, can you try `If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False` before updating the `rd` recordset?

Comment: I implemented it this way, the same error above still persists.             With rd
        If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
            .AddNew
            !TransID = lngTransId
            !ItemRecepID = lngItemRecepId
            .Update

Comment: Also the form is bound to another different table called registration.Table sched has a foreign key called RegNo (see pic above)

Comment: @ Liberty Crown Infotech Any luck with this? I believe the error is caused because you are not adding a record to `rt` in RecpSchedule2(). You are only adding to ItemRecep (ri) and TransDetailRecep (rd) therefore you "break" the parent-child relationship.

Comment: Exactly! that is the idea. Multiple items (ItemRecep i.e items scheduled for payment at the reception) are  allocated to a single customer transaction.

Comment: Kostas K.How have you been doing? I had enough time over the weekend to look at the manual ID concept. Eventually it worked. Thanks to you!